# Il me faudrait / Il faudrait que je

Tags: grammaire, sens, choix-de-mot

Les deux formes ci-dessous sont-elles toutes les deux correctes ? la signification est-elle la même ?

> Il me faudrait trouver une alternative.
>
> Il faudrait que je trouve une alternative.

Comment: This question is here:https://french.stackexchange.com/q/34113/17649

Comment: Thanks good to know, should I remove my question or flag it myself as duplicate ?

Comment: I'm not sure about that; when removed by the author it disappears; flagged as duplicate it is retained for reading.

Comment: See also here https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29576/trois-tournures-pour-lobligation-il-lui-faut-il-doit-il-faut-qui